# Android Fragments Flavor-Passing data

Tags: android, android-fragments

i am struggling to parse value with bundle from activity to fragments.
the question is on treehouse:

"I created a new fragment to store our news items. It's called NewsItemFragment.java. When I went to add a constructor to pass in the selected index, Android Studio told me that I shouldn't do that.
Can you please help me by using a bundle to pass the index to my new NewsItemFragment when it is selected? (I added a constant key for the index in NewsItemFragment.java"
here is the link with the code:

https://teamtreehouse.com/community/i-created-a-new-fragment-to-store-our-news-items-its-called-newsitemfragmentjava-when-i-went-to-add-a-constructor-to

please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your `NewsItemFragment` like this:

```
public static NewsItemFragment createInstance(int index) {
        NewsItemFragment fragment = new NewsItemFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("news_item_index", index);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }
```

and get data from `NewsItemFragment`:

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
             int index = bundle.getInt("news_item_index");
        }
```

And `MainActivity`

```
@Override
    public void onNewsItemSelected(int index) {
        NewsItemFragment fragment = NewsItemFragment.createInstance(index);
        // TODO: how do we pass arguments to the new Fragment?
```

Comment: i am updating index from previous block,how do i access bundle you created?

Comment: I created above: `and get data from NewsItemFragment`

Comment: the index is on onCreateView(), so i am trying to access the new bundle to update the line which say int index = 0; the error occurs and it's saying the bundle got private modifier

Answer (score 0):

Fragments need constructor with no arguments if you want pass some some values to fragment you can do this trick:

assume we have a fragment named History

and I want to pass 'id' to this fragment when i create it in activity

```
 public class History extends Fragment {


    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters


    public static final String ID="id";


    public History() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     *
     * @return A new instance of fragment History.
     */
    public static History newInstance(String id) {
        History fragment = new History();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ID,id);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

then you can access your stored values anywhere in the fragment using getArguments() method

use the static method newInstance(String id) to create the fragment:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                         .add(R.id.history,History.newInstance("id")).commit();
```